# Showing only first line of text then ellipses on safari and firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is working on Chrome:

```css
#coupon-description{
    overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="coupon-description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. <b>Lorem</b> Sed <b>elit.</b> cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at <i>Lorem</i> nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. <i>dapibus</i> Fusce nec tellus sed <b>Duis</b> augue semper porta. <b>imperdiet.</b> Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu <i>sem</i> eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur <i>massa.</i> sodales ligula in libero. <b>per</b> <h2>Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor.</h2> Pellentesque nibh. <b>libero.</b> Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem <b>Pellentesque</b> at dolor. Maecenas mattis. <b>Aenean</b> Sed convallis tristique <b>Aenean</b> sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc <b>mattis.</b> egestas <b>dolor.</b> porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis <i>sem.</i> quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt <b>aliquet.</b> sed, euismod in, <b>metus</b> nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti <b>nibh.</b> sociosqu ad <b>sed,</b> litora torquent <i>ipsum.</i> per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec <i>aptent</i> ante. Sed lacinia, <b>per</b> urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut <b>diam,</b> fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu <b>sapien.</b> magna luctus suscipit. Sed <b>Suspendisse</b> lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus <b>magna</b> magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra <i>magna</i> auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante <i>auctor,</i> ipsum <b>mattis</b> primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia <b>ipsum</b> molestie dui. Praesent <i>ipsum</i> blandit dolor. Sed non <b>posuere</b> quam. In vel mi sit amet <b>molestie</b> augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede <b>augue</b> facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec.</p>
</div>
```

On safari and firefox, it's like it shows all of the content inside of my small border box but it shows every few lines with ellipses, so that's being read somehow, but I want to hide EVERYTHING except the first line of any html markup that the user adds here

How can I force this to work on safari and firefox as well as it does on chrome?

Comment: The element's width must be constrained in px. Width in % won't work.

Comment: But it's in a grid, so it's dynamic and responsive. It works in Chrome with percentages?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your snippet displays the same on Firefox and Chrome for me (on a Windows machine).

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` is not inheritable, so in your snippet, text-overflow is only being applied to the third line as that’s the only line that’s part of `coupon-description` div. The `p` tag is a child and so the text-overflow won’t apply.

You have an `h2` tag embedded in your `p` tag. Per the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) “paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing

tag.”

And using percentage to define the width of the container you’re applying `overflow: hidden` will work.

```html
<div style="width: 33%; margin: 2rem auto;">
        <p style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, harum aperiam. Amet saepe minima numquam consequuntur dolorem porro alias possimus veniam, excepturi quasi cum placeat ab necessitatibus eligendi omnis quam quo incidunt! Sint, illo. Magni rerum eos temporibus quis doloribus?</p>
    </div>
```